# How do I use slots and signals to pass to variables from my loginDialog class to my profile class

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt6

I have a dilemma. Ive been trying to use slots and signals to pass data from my login dialog class to profile class. The connection works but it passes an empty string instead of the variables. I've been trying for hours and would really like some help.

`logindialog.h`:

```
#ifndef LOGINDIALOG_H
#define LOGINDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class LoginDialog;
};

class LoginDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit LoginDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~LoginDialog();

signals:
    void accountTypeToProfile(QString accType);

private slots:
    void on_Login_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::LoginDialog *ui;
};

#endif // LOGINDIALOG_H
```

profile.h

```
#ifndef PROFILE_H
#define PROFILE_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "logindialog.h"
#include <QMess

namespace Ui {
class profile;
}

class profile : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit profile(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~profile();

public slots:
    void retrieve_accType(QString);
    void on_profile__back_clicked();

private:
    Ui::profile *ui;
    QString retrieved_accountType;
    LoginDialog *loginDialogPtr = new LoginDialog();
};

#endif // PROFILE_H
```

`logindialog.cpp`:

```
#include "logindialog.h"
#include "ui_logindialog.h"
#include <QDialog>

LoginDialog::LoginDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::LoginDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

LoginDialog::~LoginDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void LoginDialog::on_Login_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString account_type = "Transportation Company";

    emit accountTypeToProfile(account_type);
}
```

`profile.cpp`:

```
#include "profile.h"
#include "ui_profile.h"
#include "logindialog.h"

profile::profile(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::profile)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(loginDialogPtr, &LoginDialog::accountTypeToProfile, this,
            &profile::retrieve_accType);

    qDebug()<<retrieved_accountType;
}

profile::~profile()
{
    delete ui;

}

void profile::retrieve_accType(QString accType)
{
    retrieved_accountType = accType;
    //qDebug()<<retrieved_accountType;
}

void profile::on_profile__back_clicked()
{
    loginDialogPtr->show();
}
```

I thought I was doing it right but from the result I'm probably not. Thank you for the help!

I Have two variables from the login dialog, `accountType` and `username`. I want these two variables to be passed into the profile variable so I can use them in that class. I will most likely save them into a variable in the profile class.

Edit: I have included more of `loginDialog.cpp` Before this it receives a value from the `lineEdit` and I have confirmed this works fine.

Edit: I have included all of login and profile aswell as the headers

Comment: How are you verifying that the received `account_type` is empty? Because the code you presented will send a non-empty string. Put a breakpoint on the slot for `accountTypeToProfile` if you must.

Comment: could you please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's really inconvenient to try and figure out what's wrong from the incomplete pieces of code you posted.

Comment: @Botje im not quite understanding, in my code account type is a combo box in which you can either choose one of 3 options. this works fine. however when i am trying to pass this to profile is where it gets an empty string, i think it may have something to do with the new instance of logindialog.

Comment: `account_type` is a `QComboBox`? It appears to be a `QString` in your code

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayene yes when the user selects their option and confirms this the option gets put into a QString variable which is account_type. This works fine as the user is able to log into there account. The issue is when using signals and slots, and trying to pass the variables to another class i get empty strings

Comment: Again. This is impossible given the code you show. You explicitly test the value of `account_type` and pass it to the signal so we know it is non-empty there. Qt will not magically empty the string as part of the signal-slot connection. Something else is going on and the only way to make sure is the debugger. Very probably the string is passed to the slot just fine, but the problem is in how you verify that the signal was received. You did not share how you verify the contents of the `account_type` variable, though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SIGNAL and SLOT in new Qt code if you can help it.

In modern Qt, your code becomes:

```
connect(loginDialogPtr, &LoginDialog::usernameToProfile, this,
  [=](const QString& username) { retrieved_username = username; });
connect(loginDialogPtr, &LoginDialog::accountTypeToProfile, this,
  [=](const QString& accType) { retrieved_accountType = accType; });
```

Comment: I appreciate your contribution, however it still hasn't worked. values are still empty strings

Comment: Then please edit your question with more of loginDialog.cpp, because clearly it is emitting signals with empty strings.

Comment: How come you are not using the retrieve_username and retrieve_accType slots in the code above

Comment: I wrote C++ lambdas to do the job. Those are accepted by the modern `connect`. It keeps actions and responses together and keeps your class clear from one-off slots.

Answer (score 0):

What [Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) was asking you about repeatedly was what you seem to be doing with this line:

```
qDebug() << retrieved_accountType;
```

in `profile.cpp`, you're checking if it has data on it in your `profile` constructor, before the user even sees the dialog, if you put that line in your:

```
void retrieve_username(QString username)
```

as follows:

```
void profile::retrieve_accType(QString accType)
{
    retrieved_accountType = accType;
    //both qDebugs will print "Transportation Company" when 
    //Login_pushButton is clicked
    qDebug()<<accType;
    qDebug()<<retrieved_accountType;
}
```

you'll see it's working perfectly fine, just as [Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) said multiple times

> This is impossible given the code you show. You explicitly test the value of `account_type` and pass it to the signal so we know it is non-empty there.

And I feel like you need to read more about [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html), and [connect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#connect-3) which only connects your signal to a method, it does not emit a signal, I'm thinking you misunderstood how `connect` works because you were testing for `retrieved_accountType` right after it.